# Mixing 10/1000 Device w/ other Gigabit Devices to Apple Airport Extreme

Tags: network, airport, ethernet

My Mac Minis (which support Gigabit Ethernet) are physically connected through Gigabit Ethernet to my current generation Apple Airport Extreme (which has Gigabit Ethernet switch ports).

If I add a Apple Airport Express (which is a 10/100 Mbps device does not support Gigabit) will it negatively affect network transfer speeds between the Mac Minis?  Because it's on a switched network it shouldn't right?  Will I experience flow control issues?

Answer (score 1):

No - switches isolate things so you don't need to worry about hub-like limitations.